# I keep getting ""Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')""

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently using Nextjs 13 to build my front end and I wanted to fetch a .joson from a link and use it to populate my website using server side rendering but I keep getting this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" when I use getstaticprops it works all fine but when I use getserversideprops I encounter this error.

I dont want to use static side generation because my website has to deal with changes in the database. can any one help

[`My directory`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGAoe.png)

```
    export async function getServerSideProps(){
      const res = await fetch("https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/4G1G");
      const data = await res.json();
    
      return {
        props: {
          todos: data
        }
      }
    }
```

```
    export default function Home({ todos }) {
      return (
        // {styles.container}
        <div className="bg-white">
         <Head>
            <title>PAPA AIRBNB</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
    
        {todos?.length === 0 ? (
          <div>
            loading...
          </div>
        ) : (
          todos.map((todos) => (
            <div key={todos.id}>
              <p>
                {todos.id}: {todos.title}
              </p>
            </div>
          ))
        )}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

I've read about getStaticProps and getServerSideProps can be defined as follows: getStaticProps(): A method that tells the Next component to populate props and render into a static HTML page at build time. getServerSideProps(): A method that tells the Next component to populate the props and render into a static HTML page at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help, After using "console.log()" I found where the error is coming from, the data I was passing through was undefined.

for any one who is facing the same problem.

**here is the solution:**

instead of using this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(){
      const res = await fetch("https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/4G1G");
      const data = await res.json();
    
      return {
        props: {
          todos: data
        }
      }
    }
```

use this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(){
  const res = await fetch('https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/4G1G')
  const data = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {data}}
}
```

the error occurred because how I was returning the data

then you can use the returned props and loop trough it an do what ever you want with the said props.

```
export default function Home({data}) {
  
  let displayData
  displayData = data.map(function(todo){
    return( 
    <p className=' text-black' key={todo.id}>{todo.location}</p>
    )
  })
  // console.log(displayData)

  return ( 

    <div>
     <Head>
        <title>PAPA AIRBNB</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>  
 
      {displayData}

    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to ask if the array exists first:

```
 todos?.map((todos) => (
            <div key={todos.id}>
              <p>
                {todos.id}: {todos.title}
              </p>
            </div>
```

as you can see i added a question mark after 'todos'

try it

Comment: It won't show the `loading` block initially

Comment: im sorry but could you explain it a little bit?

Comment: If `todos` is null, they want to show the `loading...` div.

Comment: shouldnt you want to do it like this then

todos?.length === NULL
im not 100$ sure tho

Comment: thank you for answering, it stopped throwing the error but the json data is not coming through. it's rendering a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

We should check the todos is nullish/undefined. Because you didn't initialized the variable (todos=[]). So we can check the nullish/undefined by adding (?) symbol or &&.

```
todos?.map((todos) => (
        <div key={todos.id}>
          <p>
            {todos.id}: {todos.title}
          </p>
        </div>
      ))
```

Alternate Solution

```
todos && todos.map((todos) => (
        <div key={todos.id}>
          <p>
            {todos.id}: {todos.title}
          </p>
        </div>
      ))
```

Comment: thank you for answering, it stopped throwing the error but the json data is not coming through. it's rendering a blank page.

Comment: Did you check the todos props contains data? Please check that?

Answer (score 0):

Try and use optional chaining operator (?.) after todos, It returns undefined instead of throwing an error message when the object you are trying to access in the array is undefined or null.

```
{(todos?.length > 0) ? (todos?.map((todos) => (
    <div key={todos.id}>
        <p>{todos?.id} : {todos?.title}</p>
    </div>
))) : (<div>loading...</div>)}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, it stopped throwing the error but the json data is not coming through. it's rendering a blank page.

Comment: Try to console.log data in your getServerSideProps function to see if it is null or not

Comment: thank you, following your comment by using "console.log()" I found where the error is coming from.